# How to deal with data grid view in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I run the code and the winforms opens. Later, I enter date to column 1 row 1 for example 05.05.2023 to the next row I enter 03.05.2023 and it replaces second row with the first row.

It is how it must be. Later I add 04.05.2023 to the 3rd row and it gets replaced with the second row. It is good until here.

I have 5 columns in total and columns 3 and 4 holds floats to show total at the last row.
Both columns holds different number so the total is different for both of the columns. This is also good.

The problem is when column 1 row changes, it resets the row values on column 3 and 4 to 0. I want to make it like when the column 1 change its location also column 3 and 4 changes the rows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> dateList = new List<string>();
        private List<string> column3Values = new List<string>();
        private List<string> column4Values = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
      
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column 1");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column 2");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column3", "Column 3");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column4", "Column 4");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column5", "Column 5");
            // Add an initial empty row at the bottom for displaying totals
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if there is at least one row selected
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                // Get the index of the first selected row
                int rowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                // Add a new row above the selected row
                dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(rowIndex, new DataGridViewRow());
            }
            else
            {
                // Add a new row at the bottom
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
            }

            // Calculate and display the totals after adding the new row
            CalculateAndDisplayTotals();
        }

        private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Check if there are any rows in the DataGridView
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Check if there is at least one row selected
                    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // Get the index of the first selected row
                        int rowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                        // Remove the selected row
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);

                        // Remove corresponding items from dateList, column3Values, and column4Values
                        dateList.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
                        column3Values.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
                        column4Values.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Unselect all rows in the DataGridView
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                string newValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string;

                if (IsValidDate(newValue))
                {
                    // Check if a date is being edited, not added
                    if (e.RowIndex < dateList.Count)
                    {
                        // Get the current date value in Column 1
                        string currentDate = dateList[e.RowIndex];

                        // Update the dateList and sort it
                        dateList[e.RowIndex] = newValue;
                        CustomSortDates();

                        // Update the values in Column 3 and Column 4 for rows where the date is replaced
                        UpdateColumn3And4ForReplacedDates(currentDate, newValue);

                        // Update the DataGridView
                        UpdateDataGridView();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This is a new date being added, simply update dateList and sort it
                        dateList.Add(newValue);
                        CustomSortDates();

                        // Calculate and set the initial values in Column 3 and Column 4 for the new row
                        CalculateAndSetColumn3And4Values(newValue, dateList.Count - 1);

                        // Update the DataGridView
                        UpdateDataGridView();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private float CalculateValueForColumn3(string date)
        {
            return 3.0f;
        }

        private float CalculateValueForColumn4(string date)
        {
            return 4.0f;
        }
        private void CalculateAndSetColumn3And4Values(string date, int rowIndex)
        {
            // Calculate and set the values in Column 3 and Column 4 based on the date
            float calculatedValue3 = CalculateValueForColumn3(date);
            float calculatedValue4 = CalculateValueForColumn4(date);

            if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < column3Values.Count && rowIndex < column4Values.Count)
            {
                column3Values[rowIndex] = calculatedValue3.ToString();
                column4Values[rowIndex] = calculatedValue4.ToString();
            }
        }
        private void UpdateColumn3And4ForReplacedDates(string oldDate, string newDate)
        {
            // Iterate through the rows and update the values in Column 3 and Column 4 for replaced dates
            for (int i = 0; i < dateList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < column3Values.Count && i < column4Values.Count)
                {
                    if (dateList[i] == oldDate)
                    {
                        // Update the values in Column 3 and Column 4 for the row with the new date
                        CalculateAndSetColumn3And4Values(newDate, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void UpdateDataGridView()
        {
            // Clear the DataGridView
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            // Add sorted dates and corresponding values to the DataGridView
            for (int i = 0; i < dateList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < column3Values.Count && i < column4Values.Count)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dateList[i], "", column3Values[i], column4Values[i], "");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle the case where there are not enough values in column3Values and column4Values
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dateList[i], "", "", "", "");
                }
            }
        }
        private void ReorderDataLists()
        {
            List<string> newColumn3Values = new List<string>();
            List<string> newColumn4Values = new List<string>();

            foreach (string date in dateList)
            {
                int originalIndex = dateList.IndexOf(date);
                if (originalIndex >= 0 && originalIndex < column3Values.Count && originalIndex < column4Values.Count)
                {
                    newColumn3Values.Add(column3Values[originalIndex]);
                    newColumn4Values.Add(column4Values[originalIndex]);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle the case where the originalIndex is out of range
                    newColumn3Values.Add("0");
                    newColumn4Values.Add("0");
                }
            }

            column3Values = newColumn3Values;
            column4Values = newColumn4Values;
        }
        private void CustomSortDates()
        {
            // Implement your custom sorting logic for dateList here
            // Example sorting by date in ascending order:
            dateList.Sort((date1, date2) =>
            {
                DateTime parsedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime parsedDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                return parsedDate1.CompareTo(parsedDate2);
            });
        }
        private void CalculateAndDisplayTotals()
        {
            float column3Total = 0;
            float column4Total = 0;

            // Loop through each row in Column 3 and 4 (excluding the last row for totals)
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                float valueInColumn3;
                float valueInColumn4;

                if (float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value?.ToString(), out valueInColumn3))
                {
                    column3Total += valueInColumn3;
                }

                if (float.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value?.ToString(), out valueInColumn4))
                {
                    column4Total += valueInColumn4;
                }
            }

            // Update the values in the last row for totals
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = column3Total;
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value = column4Total;
        }
        private bool IsValidDate(string input)
        {
            // Validate that the input follows the format "dd.MM.yyyy"
            return DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _);
        }

        private void addCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have edit option set in GDV which create an extra row on the DGV? This will create an extra row to add new rows. dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 will then be wrong.